# How to grab a string using boost::regex in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

example string:

```
std::string sentence = "Hello {Bobby}, hows {Johns}?."
```

I want to be able to grab everything inside the curly braces using boost::regex, any help or guidance would be appreciated.

the string can contain {bobby|john|cindy} or {bobby||cindy} or {{bobby}} in which it'll be {bobby}. I'm trying to figure out the regex for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The overall approach and code example is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781609/getting-sub-match-results-with-boostregex).

The regex you need seems to be:

```
([^{}]*\{([^{}]*)\})+
```

This regex will not match at all unless the string uses correctly paired, non-nested braces.  If it matches, you can use `regex_iterator` to process every second subgroups in each match.

Comment: that regex doesn't seem to be valid... the error I received was "is not a valid regular expression: "Invalid content of repeat range."

Comment: @unwiseguy -  I forgot to escape braces, fixed.  No need to escape them in brackets.  Braces outside of brackets denote repeat ranges such as a{3} = aaa

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment on David's answer, you may be into territory that a regex can't parse directly.  Nested stuff like you described with the double-braces strikes me as something that you may need an actual grammar to parse.  In which case you get the "joys" of learning about [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/).  If it can't parse it, you need something *way* more specific than is easy.

Single curly-brace, fairly simple.  What's inside the double... thar be dragons.  Because then you get into things like this: "What {do you {want|here}}?"  A grammar provided to Bison can work that out.  I'm not sure a simple regex can.